# Retrofit server callback throws error

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, gson

I have implemented retrofit in my application. All server request and responses working properly. However when I execute the following line:

```
response = getRestClient().osrmGetRoute(mAppRouteRequest).execute();
```

It throws following exception:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference

Well, app gets a proper JSON response from server and I'm using Gson (de)serializer.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. What version of OkHttp, Retrofit and Gson are you using? Make sure the response is 200 and has a body. Responses with code 204 are successful and don't have a body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you check the message body before using it. If you are getting status code 200 then the response contains a message.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, actually I have checked the body, but not errorBody of response and used it. The cause was erroBody.